# SignalR with NetCore, IIS connects fails with timeout or 404 from time to time when deployed

Tags: iis, .net-core, signalr

I'm having a difficult time with SignalR. It connects from **time to time**. Sometimes it gives a 404 and automatically re-connects and **works just fine**.

Most of others fails I recieve *Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server*.

I've set the timeout to 100 secs and still nothing.

Am I missing some IIS configuration? I've found this answer with no further details...
[WebSockets don't work with SignalR Core when deployed to Prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191229/websockets-dont-work-with-signalr-core-when-deployed-to-prod/54316620#54316620)

All installed software and apps are in their latest version

Comment: For such you do need IIS failed request tracing plus tools like Wireshark to dive deeper at packet level.

Answer (score 0):

Well nevermind, I just fixed it with the most bizarre way....

[IIS CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP4nO.png)

just set Websockets to disabled!!

Comment: This only hides the true culprit, and also hurts performance.